# How to center this span inside the div content to look the same in all browsers?

Tags: html, css, firefox

I am having trouble centering a particular text inside a div that will look completely the same in all browsers, chrome, IE, and firefox. I need the span  .data-box span to be centered inside the div .data-box. The problem is the code below works in centering the span in chrome, but in firefox, it is not centered perfectly rather thrown off a bit. So the question is what alternative way can I use to center things to work the same in all browsers?

Here's what it looks like, left is chrome, right is firefox. You can see the number is slightly off to the bottom and not centered. 
https://i.imgur.com/8paRgtn.png

```css
.data-item-container {
  width: 255px;
  height: 100%;
}

.data-item {
  width: 50%;
  height: 29px;
  position: relative;
  top: 17px;
  left: 12px;
  float: left;
}

.data-box {
  width: 48px;
  height: 16px;
  background-color: #282a36;
  border: 2px solid #44475a;
  border-radius: 14px;
  float: left;
  font-family: "Roboto", arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 11px;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: 600;
  position: relative;
}

.data-box span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.data-text {
  position: relative;
  left: 8px;
  top: 5px;
  font-family: "Roboto", arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 9px;
  color: red;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  opacity: .5;
  letter-spacing: .7px;
}
```

```html
<div class="data-item-container">
  <div class="data-item">
    <div class="data-box">
      <span id="point-count">12</span>
    </div>
    <div class="data-text">point</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

jsfiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/30jmcx87/1/

Comment: it looks fine to me on win8 chrome,ff,IE11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing I would recommend is to use a proper reset/normalizer css like for example: [Normalize.css](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) which pretty much resets most of the browsers default stylesheet which makes editing css items for all browsers a lot easier and more consistent.

In JSFiddle you can check the Normalize checkbox under the CSS settings to see the effects.

With that said though, I'd personally would just center the span with text-align:center/display:inline-block/vertical-align:middle rather than the position absolute trick you've done in your example.

Like so:

```
.data-box span {
    text-align:center;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
    width:100%;
}
```

Also on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/30jmcx87/6/)

Or by using display:flex and align-items/justify-content to center it both horizontally and vertically.

```
.data-box span {
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
  width:100%;
  height:inherit;
}
```

Also on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/30jmcx87/4/)

I must however do say that it did look perfectly fine for me in Chrome VS Firefox, what version/OS are you using exactly? If you have any further questions, feel free to let me know!

Comment: firefox 53.0 (32-bit)  Chrome 58.0.3029.81 Windows 8.1. Using your examples and normalize.css, they keep jumping out of position for either chrome and firefox for some reason. Also they render completely centered in firefox and chrome in jsfiddle, but not in my development environment.

Comment: Did any of my examples work for you, or are they also not correctly displaying for you? This is what I'm receiving http://i.imgur.com/X91zN7Y.png on Win10 Chrome 59.0.3071.29 and FireFox 54.0a2

Edit: Your edited post, makes me think is that your other styling is messing something up. My best guess at first would be line-height settings. Try resetting those to 1 or so. But I also do notice that the font rendering is different, so also try to use a default font-family like sans-serif for testing.

Comment: Just figured it out it's a font issue, just like you stated the font rendering is different, so it was throwing it off. Changing the font or adjusting the sizes fixed it for me.

Comment: Nice to know that, that was the cause! Feel free to upvote/mark as verified if any of our answers helped you get your problem fixed!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to center both will be to apply property `flex` to `.data-item` and `.data-box` with `align-items: center` for vertical centering and `justify-content` for horizontal centering

```css
.data-item-container {
  width: 255px;
  height: 100%;
}

.data-item {
  width: 50%;
  height: 29px;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.data-box {
  width: 48px;
  height: 16px;
  background-color: #282a36;
  border: 2px solid #44475a;
  border-radius: 14px;
  font-family: "Roboto", arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 11px;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: 600;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.data-text {
  position: relative;
  left: 8px;
  font-family: "Roboto", arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 9px;
  color: red;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  opacity: .5;
  letter-spacing: .7px;
}
```

```html
<div class="data-item-container">
  <div class="data-item">
    <div class="data-box">
      <span id="point-count">12</span>
    </div>
    <div class="data-text">point</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But if you wish to don't use flex, you will have to apply `top: 50%;` and 
  `transform: translateY(-50%);` to both `.data-text` and `.data-box`

```css
.data-item-container {
  width: 255px;
  height: 100%;
}

.data-item {
  width: 50%;
  height: 29px;
  position: relative;
  top: 17px;
  left: 12px;
  float: left;
}

.data-box {
  width: 48px;
  height: 16px;
  background-color: #282a36;
  border: 2px solid #44475a;
  border-radius: 14px;
  float: left;
  font-family: "Roboto", arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 11px;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: 600;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.data-box span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.data-text {
  position: relative;
  left: 8px;
  top: 50%;
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  font-family: "Roboto", arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 9px;
  color: red;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  opacity: .5;
  letter-spacing: .7px;
}
```

```html
<div class="data-item-container">
  <div class="data-item">
    <div class="data-box">
      <span id="point-count">12</span>
    </div>
    <div class="data-text">point</div>
  </div>
</div>
```